# How to prevent a geoprocessing task from being run twice?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, arcgis-rest-api, geoprocessing-service

If I run twice a geoprocessing task (using the REST API), what does happen?

Does the geoprocessing service execute the two tasks simultaneously, ...?

How can I configure the geoprocessing service from executing two tasks at the same time?

Comment: Have you reviewed the Online Help on [**Geoprocessing service settings: Pooling and Processes**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00570000007z000000)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is described in the Online Help on **[Geoprocessing service settings: Pooling and Processes](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00570000007z000000)**.